# Can't see the impact of drop_duplicates when used for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I see no change after calling pandas.drop_duplicates() on the dataframe I'm working on in Python.

```
df = pd.read_excel('sample_data.xlsx', index_col=0)
df.drop_duplicates()
```

[This is the data I'm working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm4UJ.png)

Comment: First of all, what is your question? Second I don't see any duplicate rows. So it's correct you don't see any changes.

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates('state')`?. 
It is important to understand what exactly the method does.
you simply have to read the documentation:https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: `drop_duplicates` does no change stuff in place. You might want to assign back to `df` : `df = df.drop_duplicates()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues that I can see you are having with the code:

1. You are not passing a subset. By default, in panda's [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), `drop_duplicates()` will take into account **all** columns and delete rows that are duplicate in all these rows. If you wish to delete duplicates for a certain column or group of columns then you should use the `subset`.
2. You should check the effect of the parameter `inplace` therefore `df = df.drop_duplicates(['col_1','col_2'])`

And after taking into account these 2 items you should notice the difference.

Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':[1,2,3,3,1],'col_2':[1,1,3,3,1],'col_3':['a','b','c','d','a']})
print(df)

   col_1  col_2 col_3
0      1      1     a
1      2      1     b
2      3      3     c
3      3      3     d
4      1      1     a
```

If we use `drop_duplicates()` without any subset, then it will drop rows that all duplicate for all columns. This is row 0 and 4, as they are duplicates for all 3 columns. Since the default is `keep='first'` you will keep row 0 and drop 4.

If we wish to use a subset, for instance `drop_duplicates(['col_1','col_2'])` then we can expect two groups of duplicate rows 0 and 4 (because their values for col_1 and col_2 are the same) and rows 2 and 3 because you are not taking into account `col_3`. Similarly to the first case, you will drop 4 and keep 0, drop row 3 and keep 2.
This would be the output for the first case:

```
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
print(df)
   col_1  col_2 col_3
0      1      1     a
1      2      1     b
2      3      3     c
3      3      3     d
```

And this one for the second case:

```
df.drop_duplicates(['col_1','col_2'],inplace=True)
print(df)
   col_1  col_2 col_3
0      1      1     a
1      2      1     b
2      3      3     c
```

Comment: So is it correct that Python will look for rows in which the value of 'col_1' is same as that of 'col_2' when df.drop_duplicates(['col_1', 'col_2']) is run?

Comment: No, python will drop rows that are the same in both col_1 and col_2. I'll create a sample to help you understand.

Comment: But then the row for which there is a duplicate in col_1, but not in col_2 will be removed as well, and hence data in the [row, col_2] will be lost. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Hopefully with the example it is clearer now. If you don't pass a subset, you will check if the full row is exactly the same as another one. If you pass a subset, you will check if the row for only those columns are exactly the same as another row.

Comment: Is inplace True also when obtaining the output of the second case?

Comment: Looking for the second case, data in df[4, 'col_3'] is removed as part of the removal of the fourth row. So isn't what I said in my second comment true?

Comment: I tried running the code df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
it is returned as None

Comment: I don't understand why do you insist on passing a value instead of the name of the column in the subset?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204553/discussion-between-ivan-libedinsky-and-omer-t).

Answer (score 0):

It drops rows that are completely duplicate.

If a row has everything equal but a column, it will not be a duplicate, and then it won't drop.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to specify the column if you have no duplicate rows. Something like this for your use case:

```
df = pd.read_excel('sample_data.xlsx', index_col=0)
col = 'state'
df.drop_duplicates(subset=col)
```